# PCI wifi card waking pc from sleep

Tags: pci

maybe some of you saw my message from yesterday about my pc not wanting to go to sleep. So I found the issue, but idk how to solve it. Here's the problem : my pc wont go to sleep mode because of my PCI(idk if it's pcie but whatever) wifi card. Whenever I unplug my wifi card, my pc goes to sleep, but when it's plugged in, my pc turn on sleep mode for a sec and turn on again. I tried disabling every parameter about this in the bios but it didnt change anything. Do you have any solution? thanks :)

Comment: Vague generalities are insufficient. Edit your question and add specifics: version of Ubuntu; wifi card type; computer specs.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please edit the question and include the output of the following commands. `iwconfig | grep "Power Management` and if it's a USB card: `lsusb` or if it's not a USB card `lspci -knn | grep -A3 Network` Please don't forget to format the output as code, simply use your mouse cursor to highlight the code and then press CTRL+K to automatically format it before you click save. Thanks.